# Weird UITextView behavior

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have a UITextView which i create in the code:

```
myView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,5,220,50)];
myView.editable = YES;
myView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
myView.bounces = NO;
myView.delegate = self;
```

I set UIView *myView in the header as well..
and also set delegate - UIViewController UITextViewDelegate>

I want to hide a label every time the user writes a text
for that i check if its equal to 0, else its hide.

the problem is in this method -

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    if(textView.text.length == 0)
        descLabel.hidden = NO;
    else 
        descLabel.hidden = YES;

    return YES;
}
```

the program runs but when i enter the first letter the label still there,
and when i enter the second letter it goes as it should. then i delete those two and its still gone! (reminder: i want the label to be hidden when the length is 0) but when i press on the delete again i can see the label. Pretty weird..

I want to have the behavior of a placeholder in UITextView but this problem annoying

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You are checking the `textView.text` value before the change; you presumably want to check the length after the update would be applied.

e.g.:

```
NSString *newString = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
```